# how to handle external shared libraries, which we do not want to expose

Tags: java, libraries, java8, tomcat

We have 800-900 services we expose via an ESB. Each service is a web app hosted on Tomcat servers. We have 4 tomcat servers per group of services. Our services are split into 4 groups.

Each service (web app) is free to include external libraries in their WEB-INF\lib folder.

The server class path tomcat\lib only contains a few hand picked libraries which are common for all services. Recently we added one more library to tomcat\lib, however it has dependencies to 4 other libraries, so a total of 5 libraries are added to the server class path.

The developers will see that 5 libraries are added to the server class path, and will start using all 5 libraries, whereas the intention was only to expose 1.

How is this best handled?

The platform team is thinking to add an "internal" service as a web app, and let this web-app contain the 4 dependent libraries, and then use a http call from the tomcat\lib\jar to the web-app, and in that way hide the 4 dependent libraries. This however introduces new errors that must be handled (time out, http errors, etc).